# Ggplot2 and unobserved points

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the two following data vectors :

```
Time <-  c(0.000,4.432,7.824,8.998,9.959,12.790,16.070,18.301,21.549,24.213,25.365, 26.924,27.773,28.917,30.541,32.716)
Score <- c(0.00,9.15,9.41,8.66,8.19,7.72,7.42,7.14,6.67,6.27,5.83,5.47,5.12,4.87,4.65, 0.00)
```

Time and Score have the same length.

Then I create the data frame :

```
myData <- cbind(Time, Score)
myData <- as.data.frame(myData)
```

Then I plot Score in function of Time thanks to ggplot2 :

```
options(repos = c(CRAN = "https://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/", 
              CRANextra = "https://mirrors.ebi.ac.uk/CRAN/"))
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
myData$Time <- as.numeric(as.character(myData$Time))
myData$Score <- as.numeric(as.character(myData$Score))
myGraph <- ggplot(myData, aes(x=Time, y=Score)) 
myGraph + geom_point()
```

Then I want to join each two successive points by a simple line (which is then unique as determined by these two points). So I use the following code :

```
myGraph + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

But now, I would like to be able to compute the Time value (which may not be in my data set) that corresponds to a given value of Score (which may not be in my data set).

For instance, I want the Time that corresponds to a Score equal to
    max(myData$Score)/2
As in my dataset, this point is not present, I want to have the Time that corresponds to it in the segment that joins the two observed points within which is the point I am trying to calculate the coordinates.

Comment: Do you mean [linear equation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/matlib/vignettes/linear-equations.html)? If so you can try to calculate the slope between two points `m <- (Score[2]-Score[1])/(Time[2]-Time[1])`, then for the first two points you could simply solve the linear formular using `solve(m, max(myData$Score)/2)`. And the plot: `myGraph + geom_point() + geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=solve(m, max(myData$Score)/2))+
  geom_hline(yintercept=max(myData$Score)/2)`

Comment: I see the method. However, by solving the linear equation to find the x that corresponds to max(myData$Score)/2 say I get x=2. But this value 2 does not make sense as the scale of the x-axis is Time (seconds). How can I convert the value I get from solving the equation into a value I can interprete as a Time ?